# How to split emoji from each other python?

Tags: python, emoji

I need to split emoji from each other 
for example

```
EM = 'Hey '
EM.split()
```

If we split it we will have

```
['Hey' ,'']
```

I want to have

```
['hey' , '' , '' , '']
```

and I want it to be applied to all emojis.

Comment: Emojis are hard! I don't know if there is some readily available library to deal with this in particular, but take a look at [this answer about flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276977/how-to-extract-emojis-and-flags-from-strings-in-python/49278212#49278212) for a bit of reference.

Comment: list(EM) and then deal with that maybe ?

Comment: `list(chain.from_iterable(x if x.isalpha() else list(x) for x in EM.split()))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to use `get_emoji_regexp` from the https://pypi.org/project/emoji/, together with the usual `split` function . So something like:

```
import functools
import operator
import re

import emoji

em = 'Hey '
em_split_emoji = emoji.get_emoji_regexp().split(em)
em_split_whitespace = [substr.split() for substr in em_split_emoji]
em_split = functools.reduce(operator.concat, em_split_whitespace)

print(em_split)
```

outputs:

```
['Hey', '', '', '']
```

A more complex case, with family, skin tone modifiers, and a flag:

```
em = 'Hey ‍‍‍'
em_split_emoji = emoji.get_emoji_regexp().split(em)
em_split_whitespace = [substr.split() for substr in em_split_emoji]
em_split = functools.reduce(operator.concat, em_split_whitespace)

for separated in em_split:
    print(separated)
```

outputs:

```
Hey
‍‍‍
```

(I think something's up with using `print` on a list with the family emoji, hence printing each item of the list separately. [Printing family emoji, with U+200D zero-width joiner, directly, vs via list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49958287/1319998))

Comment: Nice! Does this deal with complex composite emojis? (like emojis with skn color, families, national flags, ...)

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I think so. I have added details to the answer.

Comment: @MichalCharemza very helpful. Can you please tell me if I can simply add a space between emojis instead of creating a new list?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tokenize import tokenize, NUMBER, STRING, NAME
from io import BytesIO
sample_text = x = 'Hey 12  ‍‍‍'
buffer = BytesIO(sample_text.encode("UTF-8"))
result = []
token = tokenize(buffer.readline)
for token_identity, token_value, *extra in token:
    if token_identity in (NAME, NUMBER, STRING):
        result.append(token_value)
sample_text_de_emoji = " ".join(result)
```

Answer (score -2):

If the Emoji is 4 bytes, the first byte is hex Fx.  Regexp:  `f[0-7]`
If the Emoticon is 3 bytes, the first byte is hex Ex.  `e[0-9a-f]`

This is where 'x' is some other hex digit.

Examples:

```
 is hex f0 9f 98 81
☺ is hex e2 98 ba
```

After the first hex byte, the other bytes are something that matches this regexp: `[89ab][0-9a-f]`

Answer (score -4):

Seems like emojis are 4 bytes long, you can simply cut your string every 4. Here's some code for you:

```
text = 'Hey \xf0\x9f\x98\xb7\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7'

print text
print 'text.split()=%s' % text.split()

emojis_str = text.split()[1]
emojis_list = [emojis_str[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(emojis_str), 4)]

print 'emojis_list=%s' % emojis_list

for em in emojis_list:
    print 'emoji: %s' % em
```

will output

```
$ python em.py
Hey 
text.split()=['Hey', '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7']
emojis_list=['\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7', '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7', '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb7']
emoji: 
emoji: 
emoji: 
$
```

Comment: Not a dependable method at all.

Comment: I think emojis are not all 4 bytes long: they can vary tremendously.