# Printing family emoji, with U+200D zero-width joiner, directly, vs via list

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I have found some unexpected differences when printing, via `print`, a string with a family emoji directly, and when it's in a list. The below program

```
family = '‍‍‍'
print(family)
print([family])
```

outputs

```
‍‍‍
['\u200d\u200d\u200d']
```

when I would expect it to output

```
‍‍‍
['‍‍‍']
```

Another case of multi-character glyph

```
man_with_skin_tone_modifier = ''
print(man_with_skin_tone_modifier)
print([man_with_skin_tone_modifier])
```

outputs as I expect:

```
['']
```

Why is this?

---

Context: I discovered this while writing the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930688/1319998 , and it's using Python 3.6.5 on OS X.

Comment: This is based off of intuition, but because python stores strings as individual `code points` and not `graphemes` its possible that this distinct phenomenon is due to some random edge case that results when the parser is buffering output.

Comment: I suppose `str.__repr__` (which is called for `print([family])`, but not `print(family)`) has a predefined set of characters that are shown as escape sequences. They seem to be mostly hard-to-see characters like blank and zero-width characters. `200D` is apparently one of them, but modifiers are usually printed literally. This is all based on observation, I haven't found a written source for this.

Comment: I think repr prints using ASCII encoding. Lines 417 of https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c indicates similar

Comment: The behavior is the same as normal, try `print(['a', 'b', 'c'])` vs `print('abc')`.  It's a non-printable character. `chr(0x200d).isprintable()` Because of that, its converted to an escaped-unicode-literal. Python *does* iterate unicode per-codepoint. this happens **even if you use unicode**, so it's not an ascii related behavior. Play with it in python's interactive to make it easier to see. Think about the same behavior for `type(1) #int` vs `type([1]) #list`

`print(repr("\N{MAN}"))` does print the glyph, so I don't think that builtin applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference, as noted in the comments, is that `print(family)` calls the `str.__str__` method, while `print([family])` calls `str.__repr__`, which escapes non-printable unicode characters.

1. The `print` function converts its (non-keyword) arguments using `str`.
2. Calling `str` on containers (generally) calls `repr` on their items. Mostly this is because strings inside a container would too easily disturb the presentation of the container itself (e.g. with newlines). A PEP to change this was raised around the release of Python 3 but [quickly rejected](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-May/013876.html).
3. Calling `repr` on strings escapes any non-printable characters (but, as of Python 3, preserves other non-ASCII Unicode characters): see [PEP-3138](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3138/) and the description of [str.isprintable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable)

> Return true if all characters in the string are printable or the string is empty, false otherwise. Nonprintable characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Other” or “Separator”, excepting the ASCII space (0x20) which is considered printable. (Note that printable characters in this context are **those which should not be escaped when repr() is invoked on a string**. It has no bearing on the handling of strings written to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.)

The CPython implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c) (search for the unicode_repr function).