# Processing Sinhala letters with \u200d zero-width joiner in Python 3.7.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, python-unicode, non-english

The following issue occurs when returning Sinhala sentences with \u200d joiner.

```
def test_function():
  return 'ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!' #frens

test_function()
```

The output is returned as 'ෆ්\u200dරෙන්ස්!'(=f\u200drens) not 'ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'(=frens!). This issue does not exist when printing to the terminal or writing to a file. But occurs when assigned to a variable.

I tried `encode().decode()`, `unicodedata.normalize` which does not resolve the issue. The closest I could get was [Printing family emoji, with U+200D zero-width joiner, directly, vs via list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958287/printing-family-emoji-with-u200d-zero-width-joiner-directly-vs-via-list) where I realised that the issue is possibly due to the \u200d joiner.

Note: The code was tested on Colab.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: For disambiguatron, especially for those of us who cannot read Sinhala, could you spell out the individual Unicode glyphs in your test string?

Comment: Hi @tripleee, I hope it is clear now

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you could convert your code to pure ASCII (like `return '\u0066\u0072\u0065\u006e\u0073'`) or comments to that effect, that would be unambiguous.

Comment: if you see correct text when you print it then don't bother this. Text can be correct but if you don't use `print()` then it may use `repr()` to display it - as code useful for debuging, and it may display `\u200d` to show you that there is extra char which is not visible at screen. See `print(repr('ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'))`

Comment: when you print list `print( ['ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'] )` then Python also use `repr()` to create string useful for debuging. If you want to display list correctly then you have to create own function to create one string with all values - and later send this string to `print()`

Comment: There is no difference: `print('ෆ්\u200dරෙන්ස්!'=='ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!')` returns **`True`**…

Answer (score 2):

It is not issue, and it is not problem with variables but it is only how some tools display values.
They use `repr()` to create output more useful for debuging.

If you use

```
print( test_function() )

result = test_function()
print(result)
```

then you should see expected `'ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'`

And if you compare values
`

```
test_function() == 'ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'
```

then you should get `True`

But if you use `inteactive mode` in Python (or `ipython`, `notebook`, `jupyte`, `Google Colab`, etc.) which automatically displays value then it uses `print(repr(...))` to display it and you can see `'ෆ්\u200dරෙන්ස්!'`

You get the same result using manually

```
print(repr('ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!'))

print(repr( test_function() ))
```

`interactive mode` in Python  was created to test single command and it displays result with `repr()` because it is more useful for debuging/testing code.

---

So it is NOT problem with variables and you DON'T have to convert it.
You have to only manually use `print()` to display values.

---

Similar problem is with printing `list`.

To print `list` it has to convert to string and it also use `repr()` to create result more useful for debuging (or to create string which you can later use with `eval()` to recreate `list`)

If you want to see list with correct strings then you have to manually convert it to string

```
data = ['ෆ්‍රෙන්ස්!']

text = ",".join(data)

print(text)
```